# Run commands from debian package rules?

Tags: debian, debian-installer

I'm trying to do something similar to what is described in this [Q/A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265462/how-should-i-change-folder-permissions-during-package-installation#265462), except I'm using `setfacl`.

I have the following in `debian/rules`:

```
...
override_dh_fixperms:
    dh_fixperms
    setfacl -m u:applicationX:rw /etc/NetworkManager/
```

The package is built on a Jenkins server. It returns the error:

```
make[2]: setfacl: Command not found
```

I was expecting that these commands would be run during the installation process, I know the devices installing the package will have `setfacl`. Instead it seems the command is running on the Jenkins server during the build process.

Am I misunderstanding how to do the above? Is there a rule I can have run on the target machine instead?

*Also note the file being modified isn't part of my package itself.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t store ACLs during the package build, you need to set them after the package is installed, in the package’s `postinst`. To do this, create a file named `postinst` in your `debian` directory, and add the `setfacl` command there. You’ll also need to add a dependency on `acl` in your `control` file.

The fact that `/etc/NetworkManager` doesn’t belong to your package does add an additional twist, but I imagine your package isn’t destined to be uploaded to the Debian archives... You would also normally have to jump through some hoops to deal with the possibility that `/etc/NetworkManager` is deleted and re-created without the ACLs, but that seems rather unlikely in practice.