# How to handle failed dependencies during installation of a deb package (with dpkg)

Tags: debian, software-installation, dependencies, debian-installer

TL;DR;

If somebody installs my `deb` package with `sudo dpkg -i example.deb`, is there a way to add some custom actions (shell commands, similar to `postinst`) in case of installation with failed dependencies (as the package is actually unpacked and present on the target machine)?

---

Suppose a `deb` package has some UI dependencies, but the target machine is Ubuntu server.
Running `sudo dpkg -i example.deb` leads to

```
(Reading database ... 59708 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack ./example.deb ...
Unpacking example (13) over (11) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of example:
 example depends on libappindicator1; however:
  Package libappindicator1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package example (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 example
```

The result is - extracted package (I can find the content in `/opt`), the exit code is `1` (`echo $?`), but the `postinst` script is not executed. The software can work without its UI, so this is not a big deal (until I create two separate installers - one with UI and one - without).

The problem is that I have some important steps in the `postinst` script, but it's not executed at all.

Maybe I need to have some kind of rollback procedure or a way to handle such errors, but I wasn't able to find any way to do this, although it sounds trivial.

An alternative approach would be to execute the required steps *after* unpacking and *before* dependency reslution, but I didn't find anything like this as well.

Obviously, I'm missing something fundamental here. Any ideas?

---

Edit: even more, if the missing package is later present, the installation is also incomplete / broken, as `postinst` was never actually executed.
As this sounds pretty straight forward, I guess there's an easy solution about this, which I can't find.

Comment: The install command is not `sudo dpkg -i example.deb` but e.g. `sudo gdebi example.deb` : Then the dependencies are also installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `postinst` will never be run if the package’s dependencies aren’t present and configured. You *could* cheat by setting things up in `preinst` (although that happens before your package is unpacked), but I think a better approach would be to move your GUI dependencies to “Recommends”. Since your package can work without the UI dependencies, it shouldn’t depend on them, it should recommend them; this will allow the package to be configured when they aren’t present.

Comment: The steps I need are setting unix permissions (including sticky bit, which is not preserved on copy), so `preinst` won't help, unfortunately. 
Sounds very strange to me that there's no way to handle unmet dependencies, which could lead to broken installation - I'd expect ability for some kind of automatic (or custom) rollback procedure in that case. 

Regarding `Recommends` - sounds like a very good workaround/alternative. Thanks!

Comment: Fixing permissions shouldn’t require a `postinst`; you can ship the appropriate permissions in your package. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/265468/86440) for an example.

Comment: As far as an automatic rollback is concerned, the options available to a package are limited: if dependencies aren’t satisfied, `dpkg` can’t even assume that `postinst` will work, because `postinst` is allowed to assume that the dependencies are present. The only viable rollback when an installation fails because of missing dependencies would be to cancel the installation entirely.

Comment: Regarding the permissions - I never actually tried that (my bad), but I assumed I need to set the sticky bit during `postinst` and setting the permissions in advance won't work. The point is - sticky bit is not preserved on move/copy/rename/etc, as mentioned above. But as I don't really know how `dpkg` works, I should try that. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Sticky bits are stored in tarballs, and preserved when root extracts them; that’s what matters for a package.

Comment: That's freaking awesome! Thanks a lot, appreciated!

Comment: Hm, looks like `override_dh_fixperms` is **not** executed in the case of broken dependencies.  
I also tried setting the correct file permissions **before** executing `dpkg-deb` (in other words - using preset file permissions). This also failed - the installed files had standard permissions. 
This leaves me with nothing more, but using `Recommends`. Or I'm doing something wrong with the other two options?

Comment: `dh_fixperms` runs during the build, not during installation. Please ask a new question with details of what you’re doing.

Comment: I tried plenty of things, but I didn't make it. Here's a follow up question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/583140/unable-to-set-sticky-bit-and-file-owner-in-debian-package