# Unable to set setuid bit and file owner in debian package

Tags: debian, software-installation, debian-installer

I have the following structure:

`./inst/opt/test/ls`: a copy of the `/bin/ls` binary, just for the sake of simplicity.

`./inst/DEBIAN/changelog`:

```
test (1) unstable; urgency=low

  * test 1

 -- test <test@test.com> April 28, 2020
```

`./inst/DEBIAN/control`:

```
Package: test
Version: 1
Architecture: amd64
Section: unknown
Priority: optional
Maintainer: test <test@test.com>
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 8.0.0)
Standards-Version: 3.9.4
Homepage: https://www.test.com/
Depends: libappindicator1
Description: Test
```

`./inst/DEBIAN/compat`:

```
9
```

So far, so good.

What I'm trying to achieve is to make `ls` owned by `root` and with set setuid bit after installation. Here's one of my many attempts to do so:

`./inst/DEBIAN/rules`:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

%:
        dh $@

override_dh_fixperms:
        dh_fixperms --exclude ls
        find . -name ls -exec chmod +s {} \;
```

but the result with and without this file doesn't change at all.

Building the deb package with

```
dpkg-deb --build ~/test/inst/ ~/test/
```

I'm obviously missing something big. Can somebody tell me what?

Note, that `postinst` is not an option in my case.

Comment: Is it the difference between set-UID and sticky text, as at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/79395/5132?  That's somewhat big.  You should probably proofread this question.  (-:

Comment: @JdeBP you're right the example with the sticky bit is not exactly right, I was playing around with the `ls` binary, but for simplicity included the text file. Could be misleading, I agree (although you can technically execute `chmod +s <test_file>`.

Comment: Changed to `ls` again, as it's indeed misleading. Also my bad about using 'sticky bit' instead of 'setuid' indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re building a binary package directly; `debian/rules` is only processed when building from a source package.

To build a binary package with a file with a setuid bit (`chmod +s` sets the setuid bit, not the sticky bit), set it in the file system before running `dpkg-deb`:

```
chmod 4755 inst/opt/test/ls
```

Then, to ensure the file is stored as owned by root, run `dpkg-deb` with `fakeroot`:

```
fakeroot dpkg-deb -b ~/test/inst ~/test
```

Checking the generated package contents with `dpkg-deb -c` should show

```
-rwsr-xr-x root/root ... ./opt/test/ls
```

Comment: Hm, what if there are other files, which should not be owned by root, just this one? (thanks for the note about sticky bit and setuid, my bad indeed)

Comment: The packaging system assumes that the default ownership is root. Anything else needs to be handled in `postinst` in most cases, because the user might need to be created first.

Comment: But creating the package without `fakeroot` leads to the following - the installed package's content is owned by the user, installing the package (if it's with `sudo`; `su` makes it owned by `root`, as expected). My point is - there should be a way to leave everything as-is, just changing one file's owner. Isn't it possible?

Comment: I don’t think there is, at least not without using a `postinst`.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot!